# HasMany relation(or any relation) data inserted but not return on the same time | Laravel | Eloquent Model

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a laravel application in which the setting_types and user's settings are saved into different models.

**User.php**:

```
/*
 * Getting the user's notification setting.
*/
public function notificationSetting()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\NotificationSetting');
}

/*
 * Controller function to get the user's settings
*/
public function getSetting(Request $request)
{
    $userSetting = $user->notificationSetting;
    // check new settings are inserted for user or not.
    if (someCondition) {
        // add new settings for user.
        $user->notificationSetting()->save(new NotificationSetting(['user_id' => $user_id, "notification_type_id" => 121]));
        print_r($user->notificationSetting); // still rec. Old values.
    }
    return $user->notificationSetting;
}
```

As you can see that I insert the relation object but I didn't receive on the same time. and if I hit again (this time my someCondition become false) so it will return the update records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `save()` method returns a boolean, you could write it like this:

```
$user->notificationSetting()
    ->save(
        $notificationSetting = new NotificationSetting([
            'user_id' => $user_id, 
            'notification_type_id' => 121
        ])
    );

return $notificationSetting;
```

You might also be able to use the `create()` method instead, that will return the instance of the model, but only if the attributes are fillable of course.

If you want to retrieve all the related records of a model at any time, you can use the `load()` method like this:

```
$user->load('notificationSetting');
```

It is also important the use the plural form for a `hasMany` relation in order to distinguish it from a `hasOne` or a `belongsTo` relation:

```
public function notificationSettings()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\NotificationSetting');
}
```

Comment: I try both methods create and save. The data is added into the table successfully but I can't able to get updated records after insertion.

Comment: It that case you can use the `load()` method (see updated answer). Also it is important to use the plural form `notificationSettings` instead of the singular.